# Jquery, how to loop inside repeater setlist?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.repeater

I have code as below,

```
var $repeater = $('.repeater').repeater();
$repeater.setList([
    { 'text-input': 'A' },
    { 'text-input': 'B' },
    { 'text-input': 'c' },
    //and so on...
]);
```

but the problem is, I have no idea how to loop the `{ 'text-input': 'A' },` Lets say I have 10 of this `{ 'text-input': 'A' },` so by right I do my code like this below but it produce syntax error.

```
var $repeater = $('.repeater').repeater();

$repeater.setList([
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        { 'text-input': i },

    }
]);
```

Comment: Well, using a `for` loop *inside* an array literal is indeed a syntax error. Why don't you just have the loop *before* assigning the list?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that, can you show me the code to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the code using simple javascript loop:

```
var $repeater = $('.repeater').repeater();

var list = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {

    list.push({ 'text-input': i });

}

$repeater.setList(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with a map function to generate an array.

```
$repeater.setList(
  // specify the length of the array you need
  // within the map function second argument refers the index
  Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => ({ 'text-input': i }))
);
```